# Why I'm getting unckecked or unsafe operations here?

Tags: java

I have two classes. One of the classes (Class_1) has a method that returns List:

```
class Class_1{
    ....
    public List<String> method_1(){
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            st = this.cnx.createStatement();
            res = st.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
            while(res.next()){
               tables.add(res.getString(1));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        return tables;

    }
}
```

When I compile this (Class_1) class, I get no errors or warnings. But I have another class Class_2, which uses this first class. In this second class I have such lines of code:

```
class Class_2{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Class_1 c = new Class_1();
        List<String> some_list = c.method_1();
    }
}
```

And when I make compilation of the class above (Class_2), I now get these warnings, that I do not like to suppress:

> Note: Class_2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

I wonder why I'm getting these errors, since it seems to me that everything should be ok - one method clearly returns only `List<String>`, another piece of code tries to assign this list to a variable of type `List<String>`. I cannot see, what is unsafe here.

**EDIT**

When I compile my Class_1 with `-XLint:unchecked` I get:

> List some_list = c.method_1();
>
> ```
>                       ^
> ```
>
> required: List [String]
>
> found: List

Why is that?

**EDIT**

I made some investigation and found out, that the whole issue is in this line:

```
tables.add(res.getString(1));
```

it seems to be a string, but the compiler does not like that. So, if I simply switch to:

```
tables.add("Some real string");
```

then I get no warnings. Really strange.

Comment: I think there's something you're not telling us. Can you include more details?

Comment: this looks like you may have pruned your code too much. Could it be that Class_1 is actually a Class wirth a generic Parameter? If you do not supply that, you also get these Errors

Comment: No these are not gerenric classes. These are two really simple classes.

Comment: Please, provide a complete compilable example.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. I've imported your classes into a project, and I don't get any warnings.

Comment: I suggest to close this question as it is not reproducable,unless the OP gives us more information.

Comment: I will give more info in a second

Comment: Okay, as compiler says run with `-Xlint:unchecked` option http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html for more information.

Comment: I provided some more information.

Comment: @Jacobian it's not sensible to add Class1 when the compiler complains about Class2... Please additionally check the import statements of Class1 and Class2: do you really import `java.util.List` in both classes?

Comment: When I compile it with `-XLint:unchecked` I get an error message that points to `c.method_1()`

Comment: @Vogel612. Yes, I import `java.util.List` in both classes, otherwise I would get an error and not just a warning.

Comment: Maybe `this.cnx` is the source? I guess it is a JDBC driver? May it contain unsafe code?

Comment: `this.cnx` is just a connection to a database (MySQL) set by `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`. I should add that I've already checked the procedure that sets connection - it's absolutely ok. The whole trouble is with `method_1`

Comment: Ups. I have not noticed one thing returned by the compiler with `-XLint:unchecked` option. It says that `required List<String>`, `returned List`. May be that should help

Comment: Chances are your list is being cast in some way. `List<String> method = (List<String>) someListOfTypeObject;`

Comment: I do not have any specific casting that is not present in my question. The whole code is inside `method_1`. I cannot understand why it should return a List, when in fact it returns a List<String>

Comment: How do you compile the code? Is it possible that you have an old version of Class_1.class lying around?

Comment: I compile it with `$ javac Class_1.java` and `$ javac Class_2.java`

Comment: Have you tried deleting Class_1.class and recompiling?

Comment: I tried it dozens of times. I even put a debugging print statement inside my method_1, and when I run `$ java Class_2` (inspite of all warnings that I do not like), I see in the console a number of strings printed out.

Comment: BTW. If I comment `List<String> some_list = c.method_1();`, then I get no warnings. So the whole trouble lies in `method_1()`, but I cannot find the exact place.

Comment: And final comment. If I erase try-catch block and simply do `tables.add("Hello world!");`, then it works, so it seems, like even though `res.getString(1)` seems to return a string, the compiler does not believe it for some strange reason

Comment: `res.getString(1)` may return `null`. Did you check that ?

Comment: No, I do not check that. Obviously it is impossible for a table in a database to have no name. So, it did not even cross my mind, that I should check it for some insane reason

Comment: @ Manos Nikolaidis. You are right. I added checking and not it works. You may try to make an answer from your comment, so that I could accept that. Thanks!

Comment: Let me get this clear: are you saying you got rid of a warning in Class2 by modifying the body of a method in Class1 and not its signature?

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou. Yes, I just modified its body. It seems like the compiler is too smart and makes even so deep checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `getString` method of `ResultSet` class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28int%29) the method:

> Returns:
>      the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null

In that case a `null` is inserted in the `List<String> tables`. That seems to be what the compiler complains about.

You should check if the `getString` returned `null` before adding to `List<String> tables`.

Answer (score 0):

please check imports and Arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class c1 {
    public List<String> method_1(){
        List<String> my_list = Arrays.asList("a1", "b2"); //<- got a list by some procedure
        return my_list;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.List;
public class c2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c1 obj = new c1();
        List<String> s1 = obj.method_1();
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```